# Why are nonzero nonconstant elements of D[x] never primitive in F[x]

Tags: abstract-algebra

If $D$ is a $UFD$ with fraction field $F$ why are nonzero nonconstant elements in $D[x]$ never primitive in $F[x]$ even if it is a primitive element of $D[x]$?

This is a question from my abstract algebra exam.
This question confuses me. From my understanding, all nonzero nonconstant elements of $F[x]$ is primitive. That is because all nonzero elements in $F$ are considered unit, hence the gcd of the coefficients of the polynomials in $F[x]$ are any units of $F$.

Is my understanding wrong? I would truly appreciate it too if you could explain to me the answer to the question. Thanks!

Comment: What are $F$ and $D$?

Comment: Ooops sorry, D is a UFD with fraction field F

Comment: Ok then I believe you are confusing being primitive in $F[x]$ and being primitive in $F$. Since $F$ is a field, being primitive in $F[x]$ means that the polynomial is primitive. For example $$x^2-1$$ is not primitive in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$. $$ $$ You should take a look at the Gauss lemma for polynomials : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_lemma_(polynomial)